# Next.js API routes returning error on deployed environment but works fine on localhost

Tags: api, next.js

I'm working with a Next.js project that has some API routes. These routes are intended to be called from another website. On my localhost, everything works fine (**tested with Postman**), but when I deploy my application, I'm getting HTTP 405 errors on all API routes.
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63W17.png)

Here's a simplified version of my API handler:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import clientPromise from '../../lib/mongo';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db();

  const { reqType, reqVariables, token } = req.body;

  try {
    switch (req.method) {
      case 'POST':
        // my code here
        break;
      default:
        res.status(405).json({ error: 'Invalid request method' });
        break;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

I've already checked the following:

- Environment configurations: I've checked that my environment variables match between local and production.
- Deployment process: My code is being correctly built and deployed (on vercel).

Could there be a restriction with the hosting provider? If not, what could be the potential issues leading to this behavior and how can I troubleshoot further?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The issue was due to the MongoDB connection string in the .env file not being properly set up during deployment, leading to an error in the database name.